# Select an uncorrelated subset, subject to a constraint

Tags: r, algorithm, performance, subset, correlation

Consider a correlation matrix, `r`, representing correlations amongst variables `1` through `10`:

```
r <- matrix(c(1, 0.61, 0.67, -0.14, 0.93, 0.77, 0.42, 0.61, 0.49, 0.97, 0.61, 
              1, 0.91, 0.26, 0.81, 0, 0.91, 0.67, -0.25, 0.66, 0.67, 0.91, 
              1, -0.15, 0.76, 0.24, 0.66, 0.78, -0.14, 0.63, -0.14, 0.26, -0.15, 
              1, 0.16, -0.56, 0.63, -0.31, -0.25, 0.11, 0.93, 0.81, 0.76, 0.16, 
              1, 0.51, 0.72, 0.61, 0.28, 0.97, 0.77, 0, 0.24, -0.56, 0.51, 
              1, -0.24, 0.34, 0.78, 0.65, 0.42, 0.91, 0.66, 0.63, 0.72, -0.24, 
              1, 0.41, -0.32, 0.57, 0.61, 0.67, 0.78, -0.31, 0.61, 0.34, 0.41, 
              1, -0.09, 0.53, 0.49, -0.25, -0.14, -0.25, 0.28, 0.78, -0.32, 
              -0.09, 1, 0.45, 0.97, 0.66, 0.63, 0.11, 0.97, 0.65, 0.57, 0.53, 
              0.45, 1), 10)
```

`r` looks like this:

```
##        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4] [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
##  [1,]  1.00  0.61  0.67 -0.14 0.93  0.77  0.42  0.61  0.49  0.97
##  [2,]  0.61  1.00  0.91  0.26 0.81  0.00  0.91  0.67 -0.25  0.66
##  [3,]  0.67  0.91  1.00 -0.15 0.76  0.24  0.66  0.78 -0.14  0.63
##  [4,] -0.14  0.26 -0.15  1.00 0.16 -0.56  0.63 -0.31 -0.25  0.11
##  [5,]  0.93  0.81  0.76  0.16 1.00  0.51  0.72  0.61  0.28  0.97
##  [6,]  0.77  0.00  0.24 -0.56 0.51  1.00 -0.24  0.34  0.78  0.65
##  [7,]  0.42  0.91  0.66  0.63 0.72 -0.24  1.00  0.41 -0.32  0.57
##  [8,]  0.61  0.67  0.78 -0.31 0.61  0.34  0.41  1.00 -0.09  0.53
##  [9,]  0.49 -0.25 -0.14 -0.25 0.28  0.78 -0.32 -0.09  1.00  0.45
## [10,]  0.97  0.66  0.63  0.11 0.97  0.65  0.57  0.53  0.45  1.00
```

Additionally, each variable has a particular "score". For variables 1 through 10, let's assign the scores `1:10`.

```
score <- 1:10
```

I'd like to select a subset of `n` variables that have correlations with absolute values no greater than `thr` (ignoring the diagonal). Depending on `n` there may be many such subsets. I'd like to identify the subset that minimises the summed "score".

This is a pain to do manually, and considering all-subsets isn't feasible for large matrices unless `n` is reasonably close to the number of candidate variables, or to 1. Is there an efficient way to automate the procedure?

---

FWIW, here's how an all-subsets solution might look:

```
thr <- 0.8 # I use the term uncorrelated loosely in the title ;)
n <- 4
combos <- combn(ncol(r), n)
summed_score <- apply(combos, 2, function(x) {
  z <- abs(r[x, x])
  if(any(z[lower.tri(z)] > thr)) NA else sum(score[x])
})

min(summed_score, na.rm=T)
## [1] 13

which.min(summed_score)
## [1] 9
```

The above indicates that the following combination of variables minimises the summed score, while having no correlations with absolute value greater than 0.8.

```
combos[, 9]
## [1] 1 2 4 6

r[combos[, 9], combos[, 9]]

##       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
## [1,]  1.00 0.61 -0.14  0.77
## [2,]  0.61 1.00  0.26  0.00
## [3,] -0.14 0.26  1.00 -0.56
## [4,]  0.77 0.00 -0.56  1.00
```

Comment: dynamic programming?  You start with the pair with the smallest correlation, then find the next variable with the smallest summed correlation to the previous pair, then keep extending ....until you have n feature.

Comment: @fishtank - except I'm not trying to minimise the sum of correlation coefficients. I'm minimising `score` (see post), with the constraint that `abs(max correlation) <= thr`.

Comment: how about filter out pairs that has correlation above threshold. and start adding the lowest score until you meet the required `n`,

Comment: @fishtank - I don't think it's that simple. Say pairs (1, 2) and (2, 3) are highly correlated, so we filter those pairs out. Pairs (1, 3) and (2, 4) have correlation coef less than `thr` so we keep them. We now have variables 1, 2, 3, and 4 in our set, but unfortunately that means we have the correlated pairs back in. If I've misunderstood you, perhaps you could add an example to your existing answer.

Comment: Seems like you're talking about something like this: `d <- as.tbl(data.frame(row=c(row(r)), col=c(col(r)), r=c(r))) %>% mutate(pair_score=score[col]+score[row], r=ifelse(col==row, NA, r)) %>% filter(r <= thr) %>% arrange(pair_score) %>% mutate(n=cumsum(!duplicated(c(unlist(t(.[, 1:2])))))[seq(2, by=2, len=nrow(.))]) %>% filter(n <= 6); r[unique(c(d$row, d$col)), unique(c(d$row, d$col))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should order the `combos` so that you try then in this order

`combos[,order(apply(combos,2,sum))]`

Then if it pass the constraint (i.e. not having any correlation above threshold), that would be the best solution and you can stop the search.

See jbaums's code in the comment:

```
combos <- combos[, order(apply(combos, 2, function(x) sum(score[x])))];
for(i in seq_len(ncol(combos))) {
    z <- abs(r[combos[, i], combos[, i]]); 
    if(!any(z[lower.tri(z)] > thr)) break()
}

> combos[, i]
[1] 1 2 4 6
```

Comment: This is a nice idea (where scores are equal to indices it works, but in general it would be `combos[, order(apply(combos, 2, function(x) sum(score[x])))]`). I wonder if there's a way to avoid creating `combos` altogether. E.g. in the case where `r` has dimension 35 x 35, and `n <- 17`, our `combos` will be a 17 by 4537567650 matrix.

Comment: A complete example using your suggestion might be `combos <- combos[, order(apply(combos, 2, function(x) sum(score[x])))]; for(i in seq_len(ncol(combos))) { z <- abs(r[combos[, i], combos[, i]]); if(!any(z[lower.tri(z)] > thr)) break() }; combos[, i]`.

Comment: @jbaums: Yup. I didn't have time to code it as it was late but you did it.

Comment: @jbaums To avoid generating all combos, since your optimization function appears linear would be to formulate it as a linear programming question with constraints.

Answer (score 2):

If you could solve this problem efficiently, I think you could solve https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29#Finding_maximum_independent_sets efficiently, by creating a correlation matrix that reflected the presence or not of edges in the graph. I am assuming that if you use very small numbers for the non-zero correlations you will produce a correlation matrix that could actually occur. If this is the case, then your problem is worst-case hard, because maximum independent set is worst case hard, although there is some hope for special cases mentioned around that link. Unfortunately, general approximation appears to be worst case hard as well.

Could you decide that you really wanted something that translates to a simpler graph problem, such as finding which points are connected directly or indirectly to each other, which you might find via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure?

Comment: I don't think it is equivalent as the "maximum independent set" problem since he already fix the size of the set but aims to maximize some function on the selected nodes subject to some constraint on the edges. Is this still NP-hard?

Comment: jbaums selects a number n and wants to find an independent set of size n. So jbaums wants to find if there is an independent set of size n, and if you can do this you can find if the maximum independent set is at least of size n, so you can binary chop to find the size of the largest independent set. In fact this is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_independent_sets_and_maximum_cliques where here cliques are sets of nodes with NO correlation between any two nodes. Note also in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem that "These problems are all hard"